# Unit Test deleting files without reason

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

In my solution I have a bunch of projects which contain content files and some static classes with string to those files relative paths. I also have some test projects which contain tests and test content files.

When I rebuild my solution the first time I test using `Run All / Debug All` some of the content files are removed from the output directory causing some tests to fail. Run All a second time puts the files back and the tests pass. Also if I select all the tests and do `Run Selected` all the tests pass and files aren't deleted.

The files which are being deleted are in a content project which one of the test projects has a reference to since it tests the files and static classes. My suspicion is that when I run the tests it cleans the output directory and rebuilds the test projects without building the project dependencies, therefore the files. However no other files are being deleted.

None of the tests call `Delete` anywhere inside them and the files are deleted before the first line of any of the tests are run.

As an example of whats happening:

`Rebuild All`

`Run All`

`Files are deleted and test fails`

`Run All`

`Files are restored and tests pass`

From then on the tests will pass until I rebuild, in which case the first Run All will fail because it deletes the files, but subsequent ones restore them and pass.

Edit:

Looking at the build logs, it appears the project with the content in it is being built, but it gets built first. The very last task in the log is a delete task which deletes all the contents of that project. This delete task is caused by the last project creating an incremental clean which finds all these files and deletes them. Adding the content project as a project reference to this final project seems to be a workaround, but it's not exactly ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that needs to be under the output folder must be put there by your build. If you are manually creating a subfolder and copying things there that won't work. Alternative approaches depend on the nature of the folder content, so you should Gove a bit more info.

Comment: The files are set as Content in visual studio and have "Copy if newer" (I've also tried "Copy Always"). They copy into the output folder when I build the solution and work normally during a normal run. It's only when I do Run All or Debug All that the files disappear. I'll reformat the post since it's a bit of a mess anyway.